# Admin-ajax.php GET CSS file (Wordpress)

Tags: php, css, ajax, wordpress, admin-ajax

The website is tested on GTmetrix [Here is the test](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/runefjord.dk/4eKiCFUZ)

Does anyone know why admin-ajax.php is taking over 3 seconds of the loading time on this page i am trying to optimize?

It have something to do with a CSS file, but why does admin-ajax.php GET the CSS file?

I am really clueless.

For two whole working days i have been trying to find a solution for this  but i really cannot solve the problem.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Are you including the CSS file in the `<head>` tags?

Comment: Also, your CSS is 100% - and it's just suggesting combining the CSS pages into one and combining the 9 JS files
**Edit:** I tested your imports and they are fairly slow to load - and you're loading like 25 of them. I'd recommend making images smaller or using a CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Theme was very old, and support told me that the bug had been fixed in a newer version of the Theme. They were aware of the bug, and the only fix was to upgrade or dive deep into the themes coding and fix it yourself.